# Trouble with Kivy Python? Function error and image error

Tags: python, image, methods, kivy

I am trying to use Kivy to build an app. 
Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line 
from kivy.core.window import Window  

class Background_Animation(Widget): 

    def __init__(self, imageStr, **kwargs):
        super(Background_Animation, self).__init__(**kwargs) 
        self.__init__= __init__(self, imageStr, **kwargs)
        with self.canvas : 
            self.size= (Window.width * 0.002 * 25, Window.height *0.002 * 25 ) 

            # bind the fbo to the current opengl context 
            self.bind(pos == self.update_graphics_pos) 

            # x center position 
            self.x = self.center_x 

            # declare the image 
            imageStr= Image("~/Downloads/psychTREE.jpg", **kwargs) 

            # y center position 
            self.y = self.center_y 

            self.pos= (self.x, self.y)

            self.image= self.pos 

            return image

    def build(self):
        self.build = build
        run =  __init__(self, imageStr, **kwargs) 
        return run 



    if __name__ == "__main__" :
        build(self, imageStr, **kwargs).run()
```

When I try to run the code, it says name "build" is not defined . Any ideas on how to solve this problem? Also, how would I make the image appear in the gui?

Comment: what are `self.__init__= __init__...`  and `run =  __init__(self, imageStr, **kwargs)` supposed to be doing, where are Image, pos  and build defined? There are almost as many errors as correct lines of code

Comment: part of my trouble-shooting process? i figured the error was due to me not using the self.name = name statement but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: You have numerous names that are undefined, you cannot return from init and the two `__init__ = ..` are also wrong

Comment: On the Kivy tutorial, there was an example that showed me that self.__init__= __init__ was a correct procedure. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: can you link to the page?